# Update post meta custom field using block editor

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, block-editor, meta-value

I have a custom mapping plugin that (among other things) saves/updates coordinates to a custom field when the user drags a map marker within a custom block. Everything works as expected except for the fact that the custom field is only stored during the initial interaction. For some reason, it is not updating the post meta during various events.

The question is how to update post meta in a custom field in response to a user interaction in the editor?

I've tried both `setAttributes` and `wp.data.dispatch` but must be missing something.

```
// register custom field
add_action('init', 'register_block_attributes');
function register_block_attributes()
{
    register_meta('post', 'api_coordinates_pp', array(
        'object_subtype' => 'locations',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
        }
    ));
}
```

```
// in registerBlockType...
attributes: {
    api_coordinates_pp: {
        type: "string",
        source: "meta", // this is a custom field!
        meta: "api_coordinates_pp",
    },
    lat: {
        type: "string",
        selector: "div.map-pp",
        source: "attribute",
        attribute: "data-lat",
    },
    lon: {
        type: "string",
        selector: "div.map-pp",
        source: "attribute",
        attribute: "data-lon",
    },
```

```
// an event where I need to update the post meta
marker.on("dragend", function (e) {
    const ll = e.target.getLatLng();
    // these work as expected
    props.setAttributes({ lat: ll.lat });
    props.setAttributes({ lon: ll.lng });

    // this doesn't update the value in the custom field
    props.setAttributes({
        api_coordinates_pp: ll.lat + "," + ll.lng,
    });
    
    // this also does not work, the value never gets updated
    wp.data
        .dispatch("core/editor")
        .editPost({ meta: { api_coordinates_pp: ll.lat + "," + ll.lng } });

    map.setView([ll.lat, ll.lng], ll.zoom, { animation: true });
});
```

**UPDATE**: I also tried this, calling `updateMetaCoordinates` where appropriate, but same issue, the changes are not saved.

```
const postType = useSelect(
    (select) => select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType(),
    []
);
const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp("postType", postType, "meta");
const updateMetaCoordinates = (newValue) => {
    console.log(newValue);
    setMeta({ ...meta, api_coordinates_pp: newValue });
};
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**: I tried `useDispatch` and the same thing. It works the first time but subsequent edits are never saved.

```
const { editPost } = useDispatch("core/editor");
const updateMetaCoordinates = (newValue) => {
    editPost({ meta: { api_coordinates_pp: newValue } });
};
```

Basically, it seems like all of these work the very first time, but nothing I do allows me to actually *change* the meta values, not even before the initial post save. The only way to actuate a change is to delete the meta field for `api_coordinates_pp` and *then* perform an action that causes a change.

Comment: Can we see the full code, e.g. on GitHub? Have you tried removing the `api_coordinates_pp` from the `attributes` list, *and then* use `useEntityProp` to get/set the meta?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, thanks for the reply! I tried removing `api_coordinates_pp` from the `attributes` list but nothing changed (it still worked in the exact same way, so I guess that wasn't necessary anyway). Here is [the full code for this block](https://github.com/CPHDH/placepress/blob/master/placepress-blocks/src/map-location/block.js).

Comment: Hi @ebell. So you've tried changing the `props.setAttributes({ api_coordinates_pp: ll.lat + "," + ll.lng, })` to `updateMetaCoordinates( ll.lat + "," + ll.lng )`, and it didn't work? How did you check/confirm that the meta wasn't being updated?

Comment: @SallyCJ, I haven't committed any changes to the repo since I haven't found the solution, but I removed all instances of `props.setAttributes({ api_coordinates_pp: ...})` to use `updateMetaCoordinates` instead. I'm verifying that changes aren't being applied in two ways: visually in the editor "custom fields" UI (after a page refresh) and by checking the API output at `?feed=placepress_locations_public`.

Comment: I've also edited the `updateMetaCoordinates` function in various different ways – using `useEntityProp`, `useDispatch`, various syntax changes – and nothing seems to make a difference. The documentation for this is not great but I've found several code examples to work from. Unfortunately, none seem to work more than one time (i.e. no editing after the meta field has been populated the first time). If I could think of a better way to add this data to the custom API, I would probably just do that, but custom post meta seems like the most logical choice.

Comment: What is the nature of the meta field `api_coordinates_pp`? It looks like it's trying to store multiple values which is a complete non-starter for this use case. Also it's unusual to be saving post meta from within a block. Can you update your code to be more complete and less snippets? Your `marker.on` code suggests this is not bound to a React user interface and there is no edit component in your question so it's very difficult to figure out the lifecycle of your block. `setAttributes` is definitely not going to update post meta

Comment: @ebell I checked your repo and noticed that your [`edit` function](https://github.com/CPHDH/placepress/blob/0f732641dfd4e278826c7e79b230faa7334884be/placepress-blocks/src/map-location/block.js#L82) isn't reading/displaying the meta anywhere and simply setting the new value? Also, I spotted an [ugly hack](https://bit.ly/3oW8iep) which could have instead used `useEffect`. So those could be the reason, and have you tried clicking on the editor's submit button, e.g. the "Update" button (after dragging the map's marker)?

Comment: @SallyCJ, yes, I've been saving the changes after dragging the marker. The purpose of the `api_coordinates_pp` meta field is to store the coordinates so I can access that data via a custom API and when looping through location posts. I'll need to look into `useEffect` as a method for replacing that `onLoad` hack. I don't know if it's possible to use React in response to Leaflet map events, so I'll need to look into that as well.

Comment: Also, thanks for your help so far, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to update post meta in a custom field in response to a user
> interaction in the editor?

[`editPost()`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/119eb3d646dfcbb0b1f40f0f249d00dda76d79ef/docs/reference-guides/data/data-core-editor.md#editpost) can be used for that, but https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/#meta-source-deprecated stated that:

> Although attributes may be obtained from a post’s meta, meta attribute
> sources are considered deprecated; [EntityProvider and related hook
> APIs](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/c367c4e2765f9e6b890d1565db770147efca5d66/packages/core-data/src/entity-provider.js)
> should be used instead, as shown in the [Create Meta Block
> how-to](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/#step-2-add-meta-block).

So that means (in a *function component*), we should use `useEntityProp` to update a post meta via the block editor, which changes the post/editor state and then activates the submit button so that one can click on it to actually save the new meta value.

**But then, here's why it didn't work**

You commented that:

> I'm verifying that changes aren't being applied in two ways: visually
> in the editor "custom fields" UI (after a page refresh) and by
> checking the API output at `?feed=placepress_locations_public`

Which means the "Custom Fields" **meta box** was enabled on the post editing screen (for your `locations` CPT), right?

Because if so, then you should know that the editor will make 2 AJAX requests:

1. Request 1 will save the post title, content, meta, etc. via the REST API.
2. Request 2 will save the active custom fields in the above meta box via the `wp-admin/post.php` route, where the request URL might look like so:

   `https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=149&action=edit&meta-box-loader=1&meta-box-loader-nonce=7be53e3b5b&_locale=user`

[image: Preview image]

So that means, your `api_coordinates_pp` meta will be saved *twice* and thus I believe all your attempts/code for updating the meta actually worked, but then the value got overwritten via the second request above and because ***the block editor does not automatically update the meta in that meta box***, then that's why the value remained the same as when the meta box was initially loaded. I.e. The meta value remained the same as the one that was last saved.

**How to *easily* fix/avoid the issue**

1. Change your meta to a protected meta, i.e. prefix the meta key with `_` (an underscore).
2. *Or* add your meta to the list of protected meta using the [`is_protected_meta` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/is_protected_meta/):

   ```php
   // Turn the api_coordinates_pp meta to a *protected* meta without having to change
   // the meta key (to _api_coordinates_pp).
   add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'wpse_408053_filter_is_protected_meta', 10, 3 );
   function wpse_408053_filter_is_protected_meta( $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type ) {
       return ( 'post' === $meta_type && 'api_coordinates_pp' === $meta_key ) ?
           true : $protected;
   }
   ```

So whether you used that filter or that you actually changed the meta key (to `_api_coordinates_pp`), the meta would now no longer be available in the "Custom Fields" meta box which then avoids the meta value from being overwritten.

<sub>PS: You could also update the meta in that meta box using JS, e.g. after calling `updateMetaCoordinates()`, but why bother with the extra code when the above options are easier :)</sub>

#### Additional Notes

1. As I commented, you should use `useEffect` instead of the [onload hack](https://github.com/CPHDH/placepress/blob/0f732641dfd4e278826c7e79b230faa7334884be/placepress-blocks/src/map-location/block.js#L371-L377). You can see a full example [here](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-408053) which uses [Leaflet v1.8.0](https://leafletjs.com/download.html), and [@wordpress/dom-ready](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-dom-ready/) for the [view/front-end-only script](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/#view-script), but the main parts are basically:

   ```js
   function initMap( { clientId, attributes, setAttributes, updateMetaCoordinates } ) {
       const mapId  = 'map-' + clientId;
       const latLng = [ attributes.lat, attributes.lon ];
       const map    = L.map( mapId ).setView( latLng, 13 );

       ...

       const marker = L.marker( latLng, { draggable: true } ).addTo( map );
       const popup  = L.popup();

       ...

       const onDragend = e => {
           const latLng    = e.latlng || e.target.getLatLng();
           const latLngStr = latLng.lat + ',' + latLng.lng;

           openPopup( latLng, 'Current latitude &amp; longitude: ' + latLngStr );

           setAttributes( {
               lat: latLng.lat,
               lon: latLng.lng,
           } );

           updateMetaCoordinates( latLngStr );
       };

       marker.on( 'dragend', onDragend );
       ...
   }

   function edit( props ) {
       const postType = useSelect(
           select => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType(),
           []
       );

       const [ meta, setMeta ] = useEntityProp( 'postType', postType, 'meta' );
       const updateMetaCoordinates = value => {
           setMeta( { ...meta, api_coordinates_pp: value } );
           console.log( 'meta api_coordinates_pp set to ' + value );
       };

       const mapId = 'map-' + props.clientId;

       // Create the Leaflet map once this block has been attacted to the DOM.
       useEffect( () => initMap( { ...props, updateMetaCoordinates } ), [ mapId ] );

       return (
           <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
               <p>
                   Current latitude: { props.attributes.lat }<br />
                   Current longitude: { props.attributes.lon }
               </p>
               <div id={ mapId }
                   className="map-pp"
                   style={ { height: '180px' } }
               >
                   Loading map..
               </div>
           </div>
       );
   }
   ```

   <sub>And if you want, you can quickly try my block by downloading this plugin: [wpse-408053.zip](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-408053/blob/trunk/wpse-408053.zip) :)</sub>
2. Leaflet has a plugin for React, so you might want to try/check it out: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation! I'll follow up on this in a few days and expect I'll be marking this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I went with option 2, using the `is_protected_meta` filter. That immediately fixed the core issue.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped, and thanks for accepting it - I was actually about to ask you if I was correct regarding the meta being saved twice :) And I thought I should just remove option 3, hence I revised my answer. (I've also updated my GitHub repo)

Answer (score 0):

To use custom post meta in the Gutenberg block editor, you'll have to enable the REST API accessibility like the example below:

```
/**
 * Registers the custom_post_meta field.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function register_custom_post_meta_field() {
    register_post_meta(
        'post',
        'custom_post_meta',
        [
            'type'         => 'string',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'single'       => true,
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_meta_field' );
```

Then, you have to use @wordpress/data module to select and update the post meta value. Follow the approach below on your JS component:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { PanelBody, PanelRow, TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * My Custom Block
 */
const MyCustomBlock = () => {
    const META_KEY = 'custom_post_meta'; // This is your custom meta name
    const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');
    const meta = useSelect((select) =>
        select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')
    );
    const { [META_KEY]: customMeta } = meta;

    const onCustomMetaChange = (newValue) => {
        editPost({
            meta: { ...meta, [META_KEY]: newValue },
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody title={__('Settings', 'textdomain')}>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <TextControl
                            label={__('Custom Meta', 'textdomain')}
                            value={customMeta}
                            onChange={onCustomMetaChange}
                        />
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If you are looking for a complete guide, check this tutorial on [how to create and save post meta in the Gutenberg block editor](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-enable-read-and-update-post-meta-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg/).